# Flex 4.6: setting a textFormat on textInput

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.6

I'm trying to set a textFormat on a textInput component.  Like so:

```
var testText:TextInput = new TextInput();
testText.text = "TESTING";
addChild(testText);

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.leftMargin = 50;
tf.size = 20;
tf.color = 0xFF0000;
testText.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

According to the [adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f9f.html) (and numerous examples on the web) this should be possible. Yet the text never has its style applied. I've tried with both a spark and an MX TextInput (and even a TextArea) yet the results are always the same.  Am I missing something?  Or is this no longer a supported operation?

Comment: yeah those were the old days.  But now, with skins, CSS, and TLF there is truly very little limit to the high speed styling you can do. Easiest for you would be just define a CSS style and use styleName="myStyle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note there are 3 `TextInput` classes.

- [fl.controls.TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextInput.html) -- this is from Flash Professional, and it's not very useful in Flex apps. It's the one that has a "textFormat" style (the Flex one's do not have such a style).
- [mx.controls.TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html) -- an older Flex component from the Flex 3 SDK
- [spark.components.TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html#styleSummary) -- the Spark version of the component in the Flex 4 SDK

The last two don't have a "textFormat" style, so your code above won't work.

Rather than trying to use that "textFormat" style, you can use individual styles that the Flex components support ... these are somewhat tedious to apply in Actionscript, but easy in MXML. The docs that I linked to have a styles section, where you can see what styles are available to apply to the text...

AS3:

```
var t:TextInput = new TextInput();
t.setStyle("fontSize", 18);
t.setStyle("color", 0xFF0000);
```

MXML:

```
<s:TextInput fontSize="18" color="0xFF0000" />
```

Comment: you could also use a stylesheet (either inline or external file) to cut down on duplication. options vary depending on whether you are using mx or spark. heres the spark info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7f3d.html#WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-1c7d3fee122a319c9d3-7ffe

Comment: +1 Lee totally agree.  Go with CSS as I put in my comment on the question.

Comment: @JasonReeves Agreed, I omitted the CSS option. But the real issue the OP was facing is trying to apply a style for a TextInput from Flash Pro to a Flex TextInput. That will never work, regardless of which way the style is applied. Note the link to the docs that the OP supplied was not docs for Flex but for Flash CS4 :)

Comment: @SunilD. yeah your answer is spot on as to why it doesn't work (which is what Nick asked).. just agreeing with Lee that CSS was a far better alternative to the inline styles Nick was trying to use.

Comment: That explains it.  All I saw was Actionscript and figured I was looking at the right place in the docs. Thanks everyone!